# Listen for events for device plugged into audio jack

Tags: events, windows-7, hardware

Is there some way, hopefully in .Net, although I could mangle something together in C if necessary, to listen for an event when something is plugged into the headphone jack in Windows 7?  To put this into perspective, When I plug in my headphones, Windows is aware, and shows me a little bubble alerting me that there was something plugged into the audio jack.  I was looking to write a program that would monitor if headphones were plugged in, and if so, unmute the audio.  When the headphones are removed, the auto should again be muted. Is it possible to listen for events on the audio jack?

Comment: Windows is not aware of this.  That bubble comes from your sound card driver.

Comment: Is there a way to tap into the sound card driver?

Comment: I was wrong.  Windows is aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [endpoint device events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370810%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).